# Problem in designing software using strategy pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, glfw, strategy-pattern

I am currently implementing a small soft, I want this soft work on Mac OS and Window OS, so I want use GLFW for Mac environment and Window API for Windows environment (I know GLFW is cross platform but that's not the point..)

My problem is a design implementation problem:
I have created a `windowManager` class that keeps an instance of a `Window` class. This `Window` keeps an instance of an object that is a `PatternWindow`, where `PatternWindow` is an interface. I have an object `PatternGLFW3_VULKAN` that implements `PatternWindow`. This `PatternGLFW3_VULKAN` has a member `GLFWwindow * _window`, and `PatternGLFW3_VULKAN` initializes `_window` with `glfwCreateWindow(...)`.

```
class Window : public Singleton<Window>
{
public:
  somefunction(...)
  initializePatternWindow(unique_ptr<PatternWindow>&& patternWindow)
  unique_ptr<PatternWindow> getPatternWindow(){return _patternWindow;}

private:
  unique_ptr<PatternWindow> _patternWindow;
} 

class PatternWindow
{
public:
  PatternWindow();
  virtual ~PatternWindow();

  virtual void initialize() = 0;
  virtual void destroy   () = 0;

};



class PatternGLFW3_VULKAN : public PatternWindow
{
public:
  PatternGLFW3_VULKAN ();
  ~PatternGLFW3_VULKAN();

  virtual void initialize();
  virtual void destroy();

  const GLFWwindow& getWindow() const {return *_window;}

private:
  GLFWwindow * _window;
};
```

My question is about the `getWindow()` function in my `PatternGLFW3_VULKAN` class; how I can create a virtual `getWindow()` function in my `PatternWindow` class in order to get my `GLFWwindow*` window of the `PatternGLFW3_VULKAN` at run time. If I am on Mac OS environment, I can create a virtual function `GLFWwindow& getWindow()` in my `PatternWindow`, but if I run my software in a Window environment, the type `GLFWwindow` of the virtual function `getWindow()` of the `patternWindow` class won't be correct...

How can I do in order to have a virtual `getWindow()` in `PatternWindow` my that returns `GLFWwindow` or a instance the Windows API screen at run time ?

EDIT:

```
class PatternWindow
{
public:
  PatternWindow();
  virtual ~PatternWindow();

  virtual void initialize() = 0;
  virtual void destroy   () = 0;
  virtual /*UNKNOW TYPE AT THE COMPILATION*/ getWindow() = 0;

};
```

```
/*UNKNOW TYPE AT THE COMPILATION*/
```

is my problem I do not know how to deal with it, for getting a GLFWwindow* when i am in Mac OS and Windows instance for the windows API when I am compiling in the Windows environment..

In the main loop of my software in want something like that

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//initialisation of all my managers ans the data ect..

  while(!WindowClosed(Window::getPatternWindow()->getWindow()))
  {
    //DO SOME STUFF
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's see if I understand the question. You have a class, call it `A`, that serves as a base class. For Mac, you'll use `class MacA : public A`, and for Windows, you'll use `class WinA : public A`. You want to define a virtual function in `A` that returns a `GFLWthing` sometimes (if compiling for Mac) and returns a `WINthing` at other times (if compiling for Windows). Is that the basic situation? If so... when you call this virtual function, how would you deal with the unknown return type?

Comment: Yours 're are right, that's it.

Comment: I wanted to add a virtual templated function in the base classe but it seem  not possible

Comment: *When you call this virtual function, how would you deal with the unknown return type?* You plan to have code call `getWindow()`; what happens after that when you don't know which type of object was returned?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your question. I just want to have my instance _window for some screen manipulation like close window in the main loop software ect...

Comment: Let's try this: Please give some example code that shows how `getWindow()` (and its returned value) would be used.

Comment: I have edited my post with an example, I think I understand what you mean, maybe I do not have to create a getWindow() function but just a function isClosed() in the Window Class ans the PatternWindow Class ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you are heading towards can be done, but you might regret it later. I would infer from your setup that you have two overloads of `WindowClosed()` – one whose parameter is a `GLFWwindow`, and one whose parameter is a WinAPI type. The former would use GLFW methods to detect if the window is closed, while the latter would use the Windows API. One problem is that one of organization: how many files contain GLFW-specific methods? Maybe you even have a file with both GLFW methods and Win API methods? That's not necessarily wrong, but it could be a pain in the long run. Another problem is that this approach diverges from the traditional object-oriented approach.

Still, let's not force you down one path through lack of knowledge. To make this approach work, you could use the preprocessor and a `typedef`. If compiling for Mac, you would use a line like `typedef PatternGLFW3_VULKAN WindowType;`. If compiling for Windows, you'd use a line defining `WindowType` to be the corresponding Windows type. Choosing between these lines would be accomplished via `#ifdef WINDOWS` (or whatever condition is most appropriate). Then `getWindow()` could be declared to return `WindowType`.

---

A better approach (which you realized in the comments) is to shift the functionality to the window objects. Instead of `function(object)`, use `object.function()`. This requires more virtual functions in your interface class, but there is a benefit that you have fewer files that are OS-specific.

```
class PatternWindow
{
public:
  PatternWindow();
  virtual ~PatternWindow();

  virtual void initialize() = 0;
  virtual void destroy   () = 0;
  virtual bool closed    () = 0; // <-- New pure virtual function
};


class PatternGLFW3_VULKAN : public PatternWindow
{
public:
  PatternGLFW3_VULKAN ();
  ~PatternGLFW3_VULKAN();

  virtual void initialize();
  virtual void destroy();
  virtual bool closed();   // <-- OS-specific code is no longer in an extra file

private:
  GLFWwindow * _window;
};
```

Then in your main function, the call would be:

```
while(!Window::getPatternWindow()->closed())
```

---

There is a further step you might consider. (The question appropriately does not have enough details to determine if this is a viable option.) You might not need polymorphism for what you are trying to do. Suppose you were to use the following declaration.

```
class PatternWindow
{
#ifdef WINDOWS // Or whatever test is appropriate
    typedef PatternGLFW3_VULKAN * WindowType;
#else
    typedef /* Windows API type */ WindowType;
#endif
public:
  PatternWindow();
  ~PatternWindow();

  void initialize();
  void destroy   ();
  bool closed    ();

private:
    WindowType _window;
};
```

This interface no longer supports polymorphism. Is that a bad thing? Do you need multiple classes derived from `PatternWindow` **under a single operating system**? Perhaps not. Here is a potential implementation file for this class.

```
#include "PatternWindow.h"

#ifdef WINDOWS // Or whatever test is appropriate
#include "PatternWinAPI.src"  // <-- File with an implementation based on Win API 
#else
#include "PatternGLFW.src"    // <-- File with an implementation based on GLFW
#endif
```

If you don't like the `.src` extension, use something else. Just don't make those files look like something to be compiled on their own. Each file would have an implementation appropriate for the API it uses. For example, `PatternGLFW.src` might contain a function definition like the following.

```
void PatternWindow::initialize()
{
    _window = glfwCreateWindow(...);
    // Etc.
}
```

This eliminates the overhead of polymorphism and does not seem to introduce a coding burden. Also, you don't have to keep track of which files are needed for which operating systems (simpler build setup). The organization of `PatternWindow.cpp` is uncommon, though.

Comment: Thank you for the further step, I have never thought of doing this like that, I find it very useful but I won't do that (maybe I am wrong) because I find the first solution well enought for my problem but I will keep the second solution for another issue in my mind. Thank you for your time.